# how do you defeat the troll in Candy Box 2?

Tags: candy-box-2

I was wondering how you can defeat the troll? I've tried SO many times, and i keep failing. I was wondering if someone could help me. Please.

Answer (score 3):

To defeat the troll, you want to have about 225 Health, and some enchanted gloves. Make sure you have the polished silver sword equipped as well.

How you will get these things

- To gain health eat candies. Yum.
- To get enchanted gloves get the gloves from the merchant and a chocolate bar either from the merchant, the squirrel in the tree above the village, or the cave
- You can purchase the silver sword from the blacksmith at the forge then equip it at the inventory tab

If you still die, try a different enchantment on the gloves or just eat more candies

Answer (score 1):

I found that in addition to what has already been said, you use the time ring to slow down time when the troll is at dark red health. I'm not sure why this works, but without a good weapon, I can only pass this with this tactic.

Answer (score 1):

I got through with only the polished silver sword, armor, and the red fireball gloves. After that you get through in a breeze. I only lost 20 hp.

Answer (score 1):

You just eat a bunch of candies, then try it. But you need the pink enchanted gloves and the polished silver sword. The candies, you need at least 200. I would say 220-250. Then, you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to kill the troll with only a 100 hp, an iron axe and red leather gloves.

You just need to get lucky with 4 fireball shots directed towards the troll, and you should be able to finish him off in melee combat without getting under 50 hp.